# Animate an image with Angular 2

Tags: angular

Let's say I have a button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="moveImage()">Move image!</button>
```

and some image:

```
<img src="ball.png">
```

I've found this: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_animations.asp
but couldn't find any documented version of Angular 2 for this library.

I saw this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/animate/ but it does not say anything to me.

How I can use angular 2 to make the ball image bounces or move it using CSS Transitions?

Any references?

Comment: What's the problem? Adding and removing classes?

Comment: What about during the animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/f9X2UfWdExhCh6oAX9hc?p=preview)

```
@Directive({
  selector : '[animate-box]',
  host : {
    '[style.background-color]' : "'transparent'"
  },
  exportAs : 'ab'
})
class AnimateBox {
  constructor(private _ab: AnimationBuilder, private _e: ElementRef) {}
  
  createAnimation:Function = (forward:boolean, count:number):Animation => {
    animation = this._ab.css();
    animation.setDuration(1000);
      animation.addAnimationClass("test-animation-class");
      if(forward) {
      animation.setFromStyles({
            top: '-20px', 
            opacity: '100',  
        })
        .setToStyles({
            top: '-120px'
            opacity: '0',  
        });
      } else {
      animation.setFromStyles({
            top: '-120px', 
            opacity: '0',  
        })
        .setToStyles({
            opacity: '100',  
            top: '-20px'
        });
      }

      a = animation.start(this._e.nativeElement);
      console.log(a);
      a.onComplete(() => { this.onComplete(forward, count);});
  };
  
    onComplete:Function = (forward:boolean, count:number) => {
        console.log("animation finished");
        if(count) {
          a = this.createAnimation(!forward, --count);
          console.log('a ' + a);
        }
    };
    
    toggle:Function =(isVisible: boolean = false) => {
    this.createAnimation(true,10);
  };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <span class="vote"><span animate-box #box="ab" class="test-vote"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></span>1</span>
    <button data-tooltip="I’m the tooltip text." (click)="box.toggle(visible = !visible)">Animate</button>
  `,
  directives : [AnimateBox]
})
export class App {
  visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Wow! That's alot of angular code for a ball bounce. Although it's a great example that will absolutely help me learn animating objects with angular 2. Thank you!